# Where to find the pubkey for a protonmail.ch e-mail address?

Tags: gnupg

Where to find the pubkey for a protonmail.ch e-mail address?

Is there any official keyserver for protonmail?

Comment: This is a question for protonmail support (or their FAQ): https://protonmail.com/support/knowledge-base/download-public-key/

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://mail.protonmail.com/keys and download the public key for the e-mail address you want. You can do this only on your addresses though, if you need someone else's public key, ask them to export it for you.

Answer (score 0):

ProtonMail utilises the opensource [OpenPGP.js libraries](https://openpgpjs.org/) for front end encryption. The public keys for which are uploaded to a HTTP Key Server or HKS.

However, on the [ProtonMail Security](https://protonmail.com/security-details) page, they advise the following:

> ProtonMail's zero access architecture means that your data is encrypted in a way that makes it inaccessible to us. Data is encrypted on the client side using an encryption key that we do not have access to. This means we don't have the technical ability to decrypt your messages, and as a result, we are unable to hand your data over to third parties.

This suggests that they do not infact use the HKP server, nor do they store the key anywhere that could be used to forcibly decrypt a mailbox.

Comment: private key is not the same as public key. public keys should be public.

Comment: `nor do they store the key anywhere that could be used to forcibly decrypt a mailbox.` Key is not enough to decrypt a mailbox and obviously has to be stored somewhere.